# How to send custom header on next click of ajax call in datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I am using [datatables](https://datatables.net/) and I want to send some custom header as due to some server side requirement. Can you guys please tell me how can I send custom header on next and previous using this jquery datatables.

Where also `serverSide: true`

Answer (score 1):

```
oTable = $('#table').dataTable({
  'ajax': {
        'url': url,
        'type': 'GET',
        'beforeSend': function (request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("token", token);
        }
    }
});
```

You can add 'beforeSend' the same way in DataTables

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how will I identify that its called by next or previous button ?

Comment: In the beforeSend function, you can determine whether you're calling the AJAX from the previous or next button. You may need to set a flag indicating this before calling the AJAX function so that you can make use of that flag in beforeSend. Or better yet, if it is in a click handler, then you could just query $(this) and see whether the ID is for the previous or next button. Note that you shouldn't try using $(this) from within beforeSend as it will be a different value in that context.

Comment: Can you please provide any example of code so I can understand better @Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Event handler for Prev/Next button gets called after the ajax query has been executed. So setting a flag and using it in ajax:beforeSend is a no go.

The only solution I could get to work is setting up a event handler for 'page' event. This event fires before the ajax request but it only tells you what page the user intends to go and not what the current page is.